# How to create a popup window for wordpress that auto redirects my visitors to another site?

Tags: html, wordpress

I need to find out the code for wordpress to create a popup that auto appears and send the visitors to a specific site.

Comment: If my answer is correct - please accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="socials">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/" class="fa fa-google-plus"></a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" class="fa fa-linked-in"></a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function()  //when the document is ready load the function
{
    $('.socials .fa').click(function(event) //when the object with both classes "fa" and "socials" is clicked
    { 
        event.preventDefault(); //don't follow the URL as normal link!
        window.open(this.href, "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes"); //create pop up 600x600 with href of the link
    });
});
```

Don't know if it will run with bootstrap, but it is working jQuery version

Comment: I just tried it and unfortunately it's not working. Maybe I should be more explicit. I want a script for my site that automatically open a popup to another site.

Comment: That's exacly what i proposed ;) Maybe you don't have jQuery linked to your website?